# Formula to calculate Level and Current Experience from Total Xp

Tags: mathematics, software-engineering

So I'm building a mobile game where I have simple XP progression system that goes like this:

Level1: 0-399 Total XP

Level2: 400-1199 Total XP

Level3: 1200-2399 Total XP

So basically for the first level the player needs 400 XP to level up. Once it reaches that the exp bar goes to zero and then needs 800 XP to level up, the XP bar goes to 0 and needs 1200 and so on.

I was wondering if there is a formula in order to calculate the current level of the player and the current experience (i.e. 400/800 when it has 800 total XP) from the Total XP.

EDIT:
So I found the formula Level = Floor(1/20 (10 + sqrt(2) sqrt(50 + TOTAL XP)))
but I still can't figure out the formula to find the Current XP

Thank you

Comment: If the existing Q&A we've linked above doesn't cover what you need, please edit your question to show how what you need differs from what's already been answered, or show how you've tried to apply the existing answers so far and where you're running into trouble or unwanted outcomes. With these details, we can re-open the question for new answers.

Comment: I Still can't figure out the formula for the Current XP even though i found the formula for the Level

Comment: Current XP from what? The level of the player?

Comment: For example when the player has 500 Total XP they are Level 2 and their Current XP is 100 / 800 (First 400 XP went to the first Level and the 100 is what remains). If i know the Total XP and Current Level and the Exp to next level how can I find the Current XP?

Comment: Did you try calculating the XP required to hit level X, and subtracting it from my total XP, to get the progress toward level X+1?

Comment: So i think i solved it: Is it CurrExp(lvl) = (TotalXP - 200 * (LVL-1)* LVL) Mod ExpToNextLevel. But is there a better way than calculating this all the time?

Comment: Store it in a variable?